# Selection and displaying values based on condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath

I have the following XML, where I have removed a lot of attributes and data to keep it more simple

```
<isoColumns TYPE="string" SID="175" NORDERBY="6" NULLABLE="N" MAXLENGTH="65" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="IN_RELATION_ACTIVITY" LABEL="Where" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="1" ISOCID="251319" LINEFEED="X" />

<isoColumns TYPE="date" SID="175" NORDERBY="7" NULLABLE="N" MAXLENGTH="10" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_" LABEL="Date" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="1" ISOCID="251325" LINEFEED="X" GROUPID="251315" TXTHEAD="Baseline data"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="date" SID="175" NORDERBY="9" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="10" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_OF_LASTCHANGE" LABEL="last change" INFORM="N" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="606525" />

<isoColumns TYPE="date" SID="175" NORDERBY="10" NULLABLE="N" MAXLENGTH="10" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_OF_REPORT" LABEL="report" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="251331" LINEFEED="X" "/>

<isoColumns TYPE="time" SID="175" NORDERBY="11" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="15" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_OF_REPORT" LABEL="Time" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="0" ISOCID="251179" LINEFEED="X"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="string" SID="175" NORDERBY="12" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="20" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="USER_" LABEL="last change" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="251315" />

<isoColumns TYPE="string" SID="175" NORDERBY="13" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="35" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="PLACE_FOR_SAR" LABEL="Country" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="1" ISOCID="251332" LINEFEED="X"  GROUPID="251243" TXTHEAD="Place for SAE/SAR"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="string" SID="175" NORDERBY="14" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="35" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="CENTER_FOR_SAR" LABEL="Center" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="1" ISOCID="251333" />
```

Using nodeJS, I have:

```
fs.readFile('data.xml', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    } 
  
        var parser = new xmlDom.DOMParser(); 
        var serializer = new xmlDom.XMLSerializer();

        var root = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml'); 
        var obj = xpath.select("//isoForms[@SID=175]/isoColumns[@CATEGORY[.!=0 and .!=8 and .!=10] and (not(@INPDF) or INPDF='Y')]/@LABEL", root);
```

I want to do a few things.

1. If the `isoColumns` has an attribue named `TXTHEAD`, I want to print its value. So above, one `isoColumn` has `TXTHEAD="Baseline data"`. I want to print `Baseline data`
   This is what I try with the following code:

   ```
        obj.forEach(function (n) { 
       if(xpath.select("../../*[@TXTHEAD]",n)) { <--- Trying to check if attribute "TXTHEAD" exists
          var test = ""+xpath.select("../../@TXTHEAD",n);
          console.log(test.value);              
    }
   ```

   });

But the result is that it prints `undefined`

---

2. If the `isoColumns` has a anttribute named `GROUPID` (The `GROUPID` will always have an int value, like GROUPID="xxxx". This value is the `ISOCID` that we see in the XML object.
   If this `GROUPID` exists, I want to put the following objects in an array, until we see the `isoColumn` that has the `ISOCID` that the is in the `GROUPID`
   So for example, above we see that the 2nd line of the xml has attribute `GROUPID="251315"`. And the 6th line contains the attribute `ISOCID="251315"` So I want to put these 4 `isoColumns` in an array.

How can I do the things I described above? I know it's a lot I am asking, but I have really run into a wall after several days attempts, and any help is really appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info or clarification

-------------------------------More info on part 2-------------

Let's take the part of xml that says: `GROUPID="251315"`
This means that starting from this isoColumn/row that has the attribute`GROUPID="251315"` we group the next isoColumns until we reach the isoColumn that has the attribute ISOCID="251315" (which is the GROUPID). Then the group ends.

So I want to do something like this:

```
MYARRAY[];
if(isoColumHasAttribute(GROUPID) and !isoCulomn.isoCID==GROUPID.value) {
   add this isoColumn to MYARRAY;
   if (this.isoColumn.isoCID == GROUPID.value)          
     return MYARRAY;
```

To be clear... When I write an isoColumn, I mean this (which is what we see many of in the XML):

```
<isoColumns TYPE="date" SID="175" NORDERBY="7" NULLABLE="N" MAXLENGTH="10" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_" LABEL="Date" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="1" ISOCID="251325" LINEFEED="X" GROUPID="251315" TXTHEAD="Baseline data"/>
```

Comment: Part 2 of the question isn't clear: can you edit your question and add the expected output for that given the xml in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about part 2, but the following should get you at least close to what I think you're looking for:

```
let DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser
 , xpath = require('xpath') 
 , XMLSerializer = require('xmldom').XMLSerializer;

# for part 1
let th = xpath.select("//isoColumns[@TXTHEAD]/@TXTHEAD", root);
for (let t of th) { 
    target = xpath.select('.//*/@*',t)
    console.log(t.nodeValue);
};

# for part 2
let gi = xpath.select("//isoColumns[@GROUPID]", root);
myArray =[];
for (let g of gi){
        gid = xpath.select("./@GROUPID",g)[0].nodeValue;
        targets = xpath.select(".//following-sibling::*",g);           
        for (let target of targets) {    
                let serializedXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(target);                       
                myArray.push(serializedXML);                     
                iid = xpath.select("./@ISOCID",target)[0].nodeValue                       
                if(iid === gid) {                           
                    for (let r of myArray){
                        console.log(r)};
                    return; 
                }                         
            };                   
};
```

Output:

```
Baseline data
Place for SAE/SAR

<isoColumns TYPE="date" SID="175" NORDERBY="9" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="10" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_OF_LASTCHANGE" LABEL="last change" INFORM="N" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="606525"/>
<isoColumns TYPE="date" SID="175" NORDERBY="10" NULLABLE="N" MAXLENGTH="10" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_OF_REPORT" LABEL="report" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="251331" LINEFEED="X"/>
<isoColumns TYPE="time" SID="175" NORDERBY="11" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="15" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="DATE_OF_REPORT" LABEL="Time" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="0" ISOCID="251179" LINEFEED="X"/>
<isoColumns TYPE="string" SID="175" NORDERBY="12" NULLABLE="Y" MAXLENGTH="20" ISKEY="N" COLNAME="USER_" LABEL="last change" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="251315"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was what I needed. I notice you use let instead of var. Is that just personal preference?

Comment: @user1960836 Glad it worked! Using let is a mostly a personal preference, though there are differences between them..